# How to write query for multiple Datasource locations

Tags: sitecore-query, querybuilder

The content tree is like this

```
sitecore
|_ content
  |_ Home
    |_ Datasources
      |_ Banners
  |_ About
    |_ Datasources
      |_ Banners
  |_ Datasources
      |_ Banners
```

`Home` & `About` are pages.
All `Datasources` are folders of the `Datasources Folder` template.
All `Banners` are folders of the `Banners Folder` template.

I would like to set the datasource location for the Banner rendering, which should work as follows.

For `Home` page, when user clicks on Browse to choose a Banner datasource, then only these locations should be displayed.

```
sitecore
    |_ content
      |_ Home
        |_ Datasources
          |_ Banners
      |_ Datasources
          |_ Banners
```

And for `About` page, when user clicks Browse to choose a Banner datasource, only these locations should be displayed.

```
sitecore
    |_ content
      |_ About
        |_ Datasources
          |_ Banners
      |_ Datasources
          |_ Banners
```

Meaning, only the 'global' Banners folder and the respective page's Banners folder should be displayed.

Is it possible. If yes, could you please share the query.

Comment: Does this help? https://getfishtank.ca/blog/generate-a-completely-dynamic-list-of-field-items-for-any-item-using-sitecore-query

Answer (score 3):

You can use Sitecore queries to do this in the same way that SXA does, albeit with slightly more complex queries as you don't have the SXA tokens to use. Here is something to start you off:

```
query:./*[@@name='Datasources']/*[@@templatename='Banners Folder Template']|query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Your Site Root Template']/*[@@name='Datasources']/*[@@templatename='Banners Folder Template']
```

Note the `|` separating the 2 queries, you can add more if you need too. That would give you the 2 matching folders for your datasource as long as those folders exist.

You would add this to the `Datasource Location` field on the rendering item.

Comment: Should this query be added in the `Datasource Location` field of a rendering. I did that and when I try to pick a datasource, it says ""::" expected at position 18.". Also, what is `_Datasources` and should we not specify the 'Datasources Folder' template just like 'Banners Folder', anywhere?

Comment: Update the answer to indicate the field. If you look at the query, it is querying by name for the `_Datasources` folder, I used that as in your example, that's what you called it. You can change that to a template query if you want. It's up to you.

Comment: You could also just use a path like `query:./_Datasources/` instead of a filter there.

Comment: It's still the same error and here is my query. `query:./*[@@name='Datasources']/*[@@templatename='Banners Folder']|query:./ancestor-or-self[@@templatename='Sample Item']/*[@@name='Datasources']/*[@@templatename='Banners Folder']`

Comment: make `ancestor-or-self` into `ancestor-or-self::*`